# How do I import a class in gradle outside of build.gradle in a apply from: file

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I am having a wired issue I am using gradle 1.9

I cannot seem to import a class from outside build.gradle

The following works

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath(group: 'com.foo', name: 'gradle-local-eureka', version: '1.0-SNAPSHOT')
    }
}
import com.foo.my.awesome.package.AwesomeService
```

The following errors out 
build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath(group: 'com.foo', name: 'gradle-local-eureka', version: '1.0-SNAPSHOT')
    }
}
apply from: file('gradle/foo.gradle')
```

foo.gradle

```
import com.foo.my.awesome.package.AwesomeService
// do stuff
```

I get an unable to resolve class error if I try to import a class outside of build.gradle, does anyone have any insight as to why that wouldn't work or what the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to move the `buildscript` block into `gradle/foo.gradle`.

Comment: But very sadly, the class is not the same with the class of parent script file , becuase they have different classloader. So we cannot check instanceof operator.   Very annoying for me. Anyone knows the solution ?  https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4007