# Is it possible to have a Gradle build script use the same repositories as the parent build.gradle file?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a `build.gradle` file that includes a repository definition in a `buildscript` block, like so:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // Several proprietary repositories are declared
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.example:foo:1.0"
    }
}

apply from: "bar.gradle"
```

I would like to `bar.gradle` to import a class from the `foo` dependency. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26111245/531762), the way to do that is to duplicate the `buildscript` block in `bar.gradle`.

However, I would like to reduce code duplication because the list of repositories is rather long and might change. Is it possible to have `bar.gradle` reference the repositories declared within the parent `build.gradle`?

So far, I tried this in `bar.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        project.buildscript.repositories
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.example:foo:1.0"
    }
}
```

But unfortunately, I still get an error saying that repositories are not defined.

Answer (score 1):

if you're not applying something within `buildscript` your buildscript can't reference it

try...

buildscript.gradle

```
project.buildscript {
    repositories  {
        someRepo()
    }   
    dependencies{
        classpath 'some:dependency:0.1.0'
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    apply from: "buildscript.gradle"
}
```